# AndEngine onAreaTouched call even when the finger is not moving

Tags: android, andengine, touch-event

```
@Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                Log.d("GameScene", "Action Area Touched " + pTouchAreaLocalX + "," + pTouchAreaLocalY);
                float x = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                float y = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    actionDistance = (float) Math.sqrt((x-ACTION_POSITION_X)*(x-ACTION_POSITION_X)+(y-ACTION_POSITION_Y)*(y-ACTION_POSITION_Y));
                    isOnActionButton = true;
                    actionKnob.setPosition(x, y);
                } else if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
                    actionDistance = (float) Math.sqrt((x-ACTION_POSITION_X)*(x-ACTION_POSITION_X)+(y-ACTION_POSITION_Y)*(y-ACTION_POSITION_Y));
                    if(actionDistance > actionBase.getWidth()/2) {
                        actionKnob.setPosition(((actionBase.getWidth()/2)*x + (actionDistance - (actionBase.getWidth()/2))*ACTION_POSITION_X)/actionDistance, ((actionBase.getWidth()/2)*y + (actionDistance - (actionBase.getWidth()/2))*ACTION_POSITION_Y)/actionDistance);
                    } else {
                        actionKnob.setPosition(x, y);
                    }
                } else if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                    actionKnob.setPosition(ACTION_POSITION_X, ACTION_POSITION_Y);
                    isOnActionButton = false;

                }

                if(isOnActionButton = true) {
                    double l = Math.sqrt((actionKnob.getX() - ACTION_POSITION_X)*(actionKnob.getX() - ACTION_POSITION_X) + (actionKnob.getY() - ACTION_POSITION_Y)*(actionKnob.getY() - ACTION_POSITION_Y));
                    double r = actionBase.getWidth()/2;
                    double deltaX = actionKnob.getX() - ACTION_POSITION_X;
                    double deltaY = actionKnob.getY() - ACTION_POSITION_Y;
                    player.shoot((float) (((deltaX*(r-l))/l) + deltaX), (float) (((deltaY*(r-l))/l) + deltaY), vbom, camera, physicsWorld);
                }
                return true;
            }
```

This is my onAreaTouched method for my onscreen control.
I want to trigger the Player to shoot something when the control is being touched.

However, using this method, the onAreaTouched method only gets called when I'm touching for the first time or when I moved my finger. Thus, the if(isOnActionButton = true) event won't get triggered if I let my finger stay motionless on the control.

Is it possible to add some methods to make the method get called even when my finger is not moving?

My goal is to get the player to shoot all the time when the control is being pressed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a TimerHandler.

Put this code in your scene constructor

```
        tHandle = new TimerHandler(SHOT_FREQUENCY, true, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            if (isOnActionButton)
                doShot();
        }
    });
    this.registerUpdateHandler(tHandle);
```

That timer will be running in you scene with a SHOT_FREQUENCY interval. You need to create a constant with the time that you want between shots.

And put this in your class for make the shot if you are touching the screen:

```
    public void doShot(){
        shot();
}
```

I hope that help you!

Sorry for my English, I'm learning ;)

Comment: Thanks, though I used another approach,  I'm glad that I learnt about TimerHandler. Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is I have a boolean `isShooting` in my `Player` class. My `GameScene` I have:

```
this.registerUpdateHandler( new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onUpdate( float pSecondsElapsed ) {

            player.update( pSecondsElapsed );

        }
    } );
```

and in my `Player` class I have:

```
public void update( float pSecondsElapsed ) {
    if(isShooting){
        this.shoot();
    }
 }
```

Now just set the boolean in your `onAreaTouched` method either by :

```
player.isShooting = true;
```

or

```
player.setIsShooting(true);
```

if you dont want to do the shooting work in the `Player` class you can just create a method to send the data ahead of time, so when `Player.update` gets called you can just reference the variables you sent in the `onAreaTouched` method.